# Duplicate branch in 'switch'. How to avoid the warning

Tags: android, switch-statement, motionevent

I have a code for my MotionEvent in Android app.
It has condition when I release the last finger (ACTION_UP), and the condition when I release the finger, but any other finger still on the screen (ACTION_POINTER_UP). So, this is two different conditions, and I need to run code in both cases.
But compiler tell me, that I have exact the same code and offers to merge this two sections in one.

How can I avoid this warning?

There is a code:

```
switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // first touch
                // some code for a touch
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: // second and more touch
                // some code for a second touch
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                // code when the finger moves
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                // left side
                if (event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex()) == fingerOnALeftSide) {
                    Log.d("tag", "Now we release the finger that was on a left side");
                    leftFingerInTouch = false;
                }

                // right side
                if (event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex()) == fingerOnARightSide) {
                    Log.d("tag", "Now we release the finger that was on a right side");
                    myBluetooth.send(COMMAND_STOP_ENGINE);
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

                // left side
                if (event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex()) == fingerOnALeftSide) {
                    Log.d("tag", "Now we release the finger that was on a left side");
                    leftFingerInTouch = false;
                }

                // right side
                if (event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex()) == fingerOnARightSide) {
                    Log.d("tag", "Now we release the finger that was on a right side");
                    myBluetooth.send(COMMAND_STOP_ENGINE);
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

Comment: ***"...offers to merge this two sections in one."*** That is what you should do.

Comment: if I merge this (automatically), it completely remove the ACTION_UP condition, so my code will not run in this case.

Comment: Hm.. It's work... Okaaay )

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this and works.

```
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

                // left side
                if (event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex()) == fingerOnALeftSide) {
                    Log.d("tag", "Now we release the finger that was on a left side");
                    leftFingerInTouch = false;
                }

                // right side
                if (event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex()) == fingerOnARightSide) {
                    Log.d("tag", "Now we release the finger that was on a right side");
                    myBluetooth.send(COMMAND_STOP_ENGINE);
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
```